# Else if ladder in Xquery

Tags: xquery

I have an xml file as:

```
<search>
    <parameter name=”Title” included=”true”>I Want to Be Somebody New!</parameter>
    <parameter name=”Author” included=”true”>Lopsh</parameter>
    <parameter name=”ISBN” included=”false”/>
</search>
```

What i want to do is if included is true and name is Title get the data of title. I searched everywhere for else if ladder but can't seem to find one. I tried this code

```
let $params := doc('params.xml')

for $param in $params
    let $title := if ($param/@name="Title" and $param/@included="true") then $param/data(.) else ' '
    let $author := if ($param/@name="Author" and $param//@included="true") then $param/data(.) else ' '
    let $isbn := if ($param/@name="ISBN" and $param//@included="true") then $param/data(.) else ' '

return $title
```

Its still not working

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over `<parameter>` elements. `doc(...)` returns a document-node, and its first child is the root element, in this case `<search>`. To iterate over the values you want, add XPath to select them:

```
for $param in $params/search/parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

For what you are requesting "included is true and name is Title get the data of title", you can just use a very simple XPath:

```
data(/search/parameter[@included eq "true"][@name eq "Title"])
```

But perhaps your question is not easily understood, as your attempt at the code seems much more complicated than that?!?

Comment: I have two xml files i have to write xquery to take search parameters from this xml file and search it in other file if they match redirect. But i need if else ladder to do it

Comment: That is not at all obvious from your question, also you only show one of the XML files. Can you edit your question to show both please?